# Delegates -= += in C# events, can this be called after each other?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

```
private NetworkSignal _EcuTxSignal;
protected Subject<byte[]> DataStream = new Subject<byte[]>();

public NetworkSignal EcuTxSignal
{
    get
    {
        return _EcuTxSignal;
    }
    set
    {
        _EcuTxSignal = value;
        if (value != null)
        {
            _EcuTxSignal.RxEvent -= HandleIncomingMessage;
            _EcuTxSignal.RxEvent += HandleIncomingMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

This will add more than 1 Event in the list, any ideas why?  -= doesnt seem to work for me.

Comment: Don't you want to unsubscribe (`-=`) from the **old** value of `_EcuTxSignal`?

Comment: Seems like your problem is due to the fact, that at the point where you unsubscribe/resubscribe `value` is already set to `_EcuTxSignal`. What you need to do is 1) Unsubscribe, 2) `_EcuTxSignal = value;`,  3) resubscribe

Comment: Also when you say "event" do you actually mean "event listener"? There's no event being fired here at least.

Comment: In any case, I can't reproduce the problem. See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Db9YYJ) - in the output, only one **handled** event is logged.

Comment: Thanks for comments, strange your example looks fine and work fine. But in my case the invocationcount always set to 3 which is strange anyway. In your example the Handleincomins...  is only executed once, in my its three times....

Comment: And like Roland exaplains, isnt -= then += very strange in a row, cause then its unsubscribed but sametime subscribed again, which may result in no'-=' execution right?

Comment: @Mikael could you solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Roland, not yet BUt havent tried during the weekend, I at least find out that this was not the problem, the problem was that .invoke(...), and one more place also touches the subscription, so missmatches alot. I will comeback with more Q if needed, Appreciating the help here!!

Comment: Fixed, found the error finally, it was two different tasks running and mixed up. Thanks and appreciated for all comments and help here!